VPN service not working for opera and firefox on Android 10+
I'm developing my VPN application by redirecting traffic from browsers to it using addAllowedApplication(*browser package name*).
And it works correctly, sites that were inaccessible before connecting via VPN become accessible in opera, chrome, firefox browsers if the android version is < 10.
Starting from version 10, opera and firefox ignore my VPN connection and do not load websites. I've looked for various changelogs on the support sites for these browsers, but haven't found anything regarding this.
What specific settings do Opera and Firefox have that makes them ignore VPN?
